# How to configure modem?

Tags: modem

I wrote program in Visual C++ 2008 for communication trough RS-232  between computer and industrial machine. Program works fine when computer and machine are connected directly trough RS-232 cable.

Now I want to communicate through modems.

I have two 56K modems (TDW-33). First modem is connected through RS-232 cable to PC. Second modem is connected to the machine (trough RS-232) that receive commands from computer and answer on this commands. The modems are connected through telephone line.

How to configure two modems to work correctly? Do I need to change my C++ code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really bringing back memories...

You control modems by writing character sequences to the RS-232 serial port.  The exact commands depend on your particular modem.  Almost all modems at least understand a common subset of commands known as the Hayes Commands.  Wikipedia provides a good overview of the commands along with some history:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

For example, to dial the number 2345678 you would send the command

> ATDT2345678

You would configure the receiving modem to answer an incoming call with the command

> ATA

or you could configure the receiving modem to always answer after, say, 3 rings with

> ATS0=3

Comment: If you want these memories to be back, work with a Bluetooth COMM module. They often speak this command set as well...